# Insert tables into word via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I'm making an addon for word. It must be possible to insert tables. It shall be possible to specify the dimensions and location. When I insert the first table it works fine, but if I insert another table, then the first table get removed and the new one inserted. I am still pretty new to vb.net so, the code may not be the best.

```
    With Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Range, 1, 1)
        .TopPadding = 0
        .BottomPadding = 0
        .LeftPadding = 0
        .RightPadding = 0
        .Rows.WrapAroundText = True
        .Rows.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .Rows.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Rows.HorizontalPosition = dobHorizontal
        .Rows.VerticalPosition = dobVertical
        .Rows.Height = dobHeight
        .Columns.Width = dobWidth
    End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the code above for adding both tables (possibly in a loop) I think the issue is that you're overwriting the first table with the second one since you use the same range.

The documentation for [Tables.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845710.aspx) says:

> The range where you want the table to appear. The table replaces the
>   range, if the range isn't collapsed.

If you change the first line of your code from:

```
With Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Range, 1, 1)
```

to something like

```
dim range = Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Range;
With Globals.WordAddIn.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(range, 1, 1)
```

And then after you added your first table you do:

```
range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

It should let you add both tables.

However, if you add two tables right after each other I think Word combines them into one table, so you need to add some space in between, for example by using something like:

```
range.InsertParagraphAfter();
range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd); ' need to collapse again to avoid overwriting
```

I think it might work.